# how to draw curve using plot function in r?

Tags: r, plot

I want to draw CDF and PDF plots with different axes. Here is my data;

```
data<-c(`1979` = 12.03, `1980` = 13.66, `1981` = 14.19, `1982` = 11.7, 
`1983` = 11.68, `1984` = 11.78, `1985` = 11.19, `1986` = 12.49, 
`1987` = 16.22, `1988` = 11.51, `1989` = 10.52, `1990` = 11.53, 
`1991` = 10.5, `1992` = 11.2, `1993` = 12.53, `1994` = 10.17, 
`1995` = 11.34, `1996` = 12.22, `1997` = 12.84, `1998` = 13.17, 
`1999` = 12.61, `2000` = 11.33, `2001` = 11.47, `2002` = 11.75, 
`2003` = 12.52, `2004` = 13.03, `2005` = 11.8, `2006` = 12.78, 
`2007` = 10.83, `2008` = 14.72, `2009` = 13.18, `2010` = 11.71, 
`2011` = 10.21, `2012` = 14.33, `2013` = 12.83, `2014` = 10.84, 
`2015` = 11.97, `2016` = 10.65, `2017` = 11.71, `2018` = 11.61, 
`2019` = 13.3, `2020` = 11.71)
```

my codes:

```
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 4) + 0.3)   
plot(ecdf(data), ylab="CDF", xlab="MIWH", main = "y")      
par(new = TRUE)
pdf<-dnorm(data, mean(data),sd(data))
plot(data,pdf, col = 3, axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(side = 4,  at = pretty(range(pdf)))
mtext("PDF", side = 4, line = 3)
```

I am getting:

[image]

But I desire green points to see like a curve:

[image]

I tried curve function, but with it I am not able to add axis of pdf.

Comment: Set `type = "l"` for lines instead of points inside of `plot()`. Or use The `lines()` function instead of the `plot()` function.

Comment: @GregorThomas I tried both but I am getting unreasonable plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you wouldn't rather plot the normal CDF (with the same y axis).

```
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 4) + 0.3)   
plot(ecdf(data), ylab="CDF", xlab="MIWH", main = "y", xlim = c(9, 17))   
par(new = TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(data), sd = sd(data)),
      col = 3, xlim = c(9, 17), axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")

axis(side = 4,  at = pretty(c(0, dnorm(0, sd = sd(data)))),
     col = 3, col.axis = 3)
mtext("PDF", side = 4, line = 3)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: I tried that but then I noticed that y axis of CDF is not matching values of PDF. Maybe I made a mistake while doing it.

Comment: I don't think you understand. I mean you should plot the CDF instead of the PDF. Then you would only need one y-axis and comparison between the empirical and theoretical distribution would be easier. OTOH, you could simply make a qq-plot.

Comment: Oh I got it now. Actually my idea was to do what you said then my advisor also wanted me to add PDF.

Comment: You could also plot a kernel density estimate (see `density`) instead of the empirical CDF.

Comment: I am trying it, appreciate for your advices and solutions.